# In Marklogic-9, upon database restore a document got inserted in one 'Forest' and its properties into another, causing XDMP-DBDUPURI exception

Tags: duplicates, marklogic, marklogic-9

In `Marklogic-9` we did a `Database Restore` (the configurations of the source and target DBs were the same) and upon completion, while doing some `read transaction` got `XDMP-DBDUPURI`.

After referring the scripts of the **Repairing Duplicate Uris** section of [understanding-xdmp-dbdupuri-exceptions-how-they-can-occur-and-how-to-prevent-them](https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/22/19/understanding-xdmp-dbdupuri-exceptions-how-they-can-occur-and-how-to-prevent-them), found that the document (for the concerned `URI`) was inserted in one `Forest` and its `Properties` into another.

Now the question is how this happened and is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: Was this a restore of a backup from the same database, or into a different one? Were there any errors or issues (availability of hosts, forests or failover events during the restore? Have you tried to see if this is repeatable? You may want to engage with MarkLogic Support to help investigate you issue.

Comment: Thanks, @MadsHansen for replying. 
1. Yes, this was the `backup` of the same `database` (the `configuration` of the 
    database was the same as current when the backup was taken). 
2. Yes, while the restore was in progress `XDMP-DBDUPURI` exception was 
    logged in the `Error Log`; but there were no errors or issues for the 
    availability of `hosts`, `forests` or `fail-over` events during the restore.
3. We are redoing the `database restore` activity to check whether the 
    exception is repeatable or not.

Comment: @MadsHansen we didn't get this error after redoing the restore activity. So, it's not repeatable.

Comment: If you have the ErrorLog from when the first restore was done, it might be worth inspecting or opening a Support case and attaching to the ticket to see if you can find out what happened.